# How to activate generic host startup message

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've set up a generic host by instantiating a host builder and calling build function on the host and running it. When the console pops up, no start message is shown.

I'm running my code in visual studio 2017. I've tried this on another computer and there I get a startup message. I'm doing everything the same way.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var hosting = new HostBuilder();
    hosting.Build().Run();
}
```

Console pops up and is empty,
I expect to see something like the following in the console:

```
Using launch settings from C:\repos\andrewlock\blog-examples\suppress-console-messages\Properties\launchSettings.json...
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\repos\andrewlock\blog-examples\suppress-console-messages
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Comment: Do you mean the same code has different (output) behaviors on different machines? How do you initialize your project code (e.g. which template, what packages are installed)?

Comment: Have you configured logger in Startup class?

Comment: This link may be useful for you as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @ChengChen thats right. Outputbehavior is different on different machines. Im using the following packages: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection,Microsoft.NETCore.App,Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting

Comment: @KamranPoladov Start up class is for configuring the DI and Middelware pipeline. Its not mandatory for initialising a Host. Anyway. I dont have startup class on my other machine either and it works there. What exactly triggers the message?

Comment: @ninipop The console output in your question is for web host that is built by WebHostBuilder, while your code uses a HostBuilder which theoretically won't print these messages. Can you check if your projects are correctly built?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so was about to give up before i finally figured it out. Its was trivial but annoying. So i compared the packages from both machines and on the one where it didnt work i had the preview 3.0.0 version of Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting to version 2.0.0 like on my other machine and viola!
Guess moral of the story is not to expect standard behavior from preview releases.